# HTML email not working in Unix?

Tags: email

We are migrating from one Unix server to another.

*Old server*

```
$ uname -a
Linux <redacted> 2.6.9-89.31.1.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Oct 4 21:53:22 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

*New server*

```
$ uname -a
Linux <redacted> 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 9 15:20:47 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When using the below command, mails were sent as HTML content in the old server, but the same command on the new server is only sending plain emails.

- What are my options here?
- what can I do to make this work?

*My command*

```
$ echo "<b>HTML Message <i>goes</i> here</b>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" -rtest@test.com testr@test.com
```

Comment: It look like redhat. Have you checked sendmail's option ? or mail ? mail now know how to attache html
 (among other) files.

Comment: Looks to me like you have your quotes mixed up (unless I don't know how `$(command)` works ... try this instead `echo "<b>HTML Message <i>goes</i> here</b>" | mail -s "$(echo -e 'This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html')" -rtest@test.com testr@test.com`. By the way, what you are doing is dodgy ... you are relying on terminating the `Subject:` header and surreptitiously inserting a `Content-Type:` header into the message - this is something a *cracker* might want to do and sounds like a good candidate for a bug-fix in the mail program (thus preventing your technique from working).

Comment: So what is the proper way then?, I want to send html mails from this new server using 'mail' command, because only that seems to work, sendmail results in a dead.letter

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably that your newer `/bin/mail` program is adding its own Mime header to the mail, overriding your `Content-Type: text/html` hack that you have tacked onto the end of the `Subject:` header.

An easy solution is to bypass `mail` and simply go straight to `sendmail` (even if using `postfix`). Replace your command with:

```
sendmail -t <<!
From: test@test.com
To: testr@test.com
Subject: This is the subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<b>HTML Message <i>goes</i> here</b>
!
```

If your sendmail doesn't accept `-t` then remplace that option by the
address you are sending to, ie `testr@test.com`.

Comment: Thanks but i cant use 'sendmail', it does not work for me.. it just gives a dead.letter. any other options?

Comment: Try replacing the option `-t` by `testr@test.com`. Do you know what software package you are using to send mail, e.g. postfix, sendmail?

Comment: get the same dead.letter, how can I check which software package is installed?

Comment: Assuming you are on an rpm-based OS, do `type -p sendmail` to find the full path to it, then `rpm -qf` on that path; eg if the path is `/sbin/sendmail`, then do `rpm -qf /sbin/sendmail`.  Do the same for `mail` so we know which mail program you are using too.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I got for sendmail `postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
sendmail-8.14.4-8.el6.x86_64` and for mail `mailx-12.4-8.el6_6.x86_64`

Comment: It looks like you must have configured mailx to use smtp instead of sendmail, or my example would have worked. I dont see how you can do what you want to with mailx. You will need to configure and enable postfix so that the sendmail command works if you want to send this sort of mail.